# TinyMCE content_css from Angular 6 global stylesheet

Tags: css, angular, tinymce

I want TinyMCE editor editable area styles to be same as my Angular 6 application. I know i can set content_css

```
content_css: 'https://testing.local/dist/styles.a9fe3df792f457e5d228.css'
```

But i have to change this line of code every time css file name changes. Also how to i make it work so i can test my application with:

```
ng s
```

Tnx for your time

Comment: Could you create a statically named CSS file to pass the editor that has the same styles as your application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok i got a solution to my problem.

Changed contact_css to use environmant variables

```
content_css: environment.globalStylesheetUrl
```

In environmant.ts i have

```
 globalStylesheetUrl: 'http://localhost:4200/assets/css/content-styles.css'
```

Installed gulp and my gulpfile is:

```
'use strict';

var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');

gulp.task('styles', function () {
    return gulp.src(['./scss/bootstrap/bootstrap.scss', './scss/mdb.scss'])
        .pipe(sass({outputStyle: 'compressed'}).on('error', sass.logError))
        .pipe(concat('content-styles.css'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./src/assets/css'));
});

gulp.task('styles-build', function () {
    return gulp.src(['./scss/bootstrap/bootstrap.scss', './scss/mdb.scss'])
        .pipe(sass({outputStyle: 'compressed'}).on('error', sass.logError))
        .pipe(concat('content-styles.css'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/'));
});
```

Also added some scripts to package.json

```
"scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build --prod",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "development": "gulp styles && ng s -o --aot",  //added this for development
    "production": "gulp styles-build && ng build --prod"  //added this for production
  },
```

Now i can

```
npm run development
npm run production
```

Hope this is useful for someone.

Comment: Thank you so much for sharing! I was stuck with this issue and your solution solved it!